# How to generate row for each ID created in or before a period of time in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am developing a notebook in **pyspark** and I have a df like this:

[image]

Where the ***created_at*** variable is the date where that ***id*** became a client. I want to transform this df into a df that shows all the clients in that month, so the output would be something like that:

[image]

I know I have to do a loop here I am just not sure how, can anyone help?
ps: I'm working with pyspark to do this development

Comment: Your question is not clear. You appear to have __dates__ when certain __id__ were created and expect to turn them into when they were accessed? sounds impossible. Please clarify.

Comment: I want  a final table showing me all the ids that were already created in the month in question not when they were accessed, is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't really understand the need for doing this, you can use a self join with condition `created_at >= created_at`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_date, date_format

# convert string to date type
df = df.withColumn("created_at", to_date(col("created_at"), "dd/MM/yyyy")) \

# self join
df.alias("df1").join(df.alias("df2"), col("df1.created_at") >= col("df2.created_at")) \
    .select(
    date_format(col("df1.created_at"), "yyyy-MM").alias("period"),
    col("df2.id")
).show(30)

#+-------+---+
#| period| id|
#+-------+---+
#|2020-08|  1|
#|2020-09|  1|
#|2020-09|  2|
#|2020-10|  1|
#|2020-10|  2|
#|2020-10|  3|
#|2020-11|  1|
#|2020-11|  2|
#|2020-11|  3|
#|2020-11|  4|
#|2020-12|  1|
#|2020-12|  2|
#|2020-12|  3|
#|2020-12|  4|
#|2020-12|  5|
#|2021-01|  1|
#|2021-01|  2|
#|2021-01|  3|
#|2021-01|  4|
#|2021-01|  5|
#|2021-01|  6|
#+-------+---+
```